# CASE and IF query only returning one conditional result

Tags: mysql, join, case

```
 SELECT a.*, IF(b.pid=a.id,b.id,0) AS bpid 
 FROM table1 a, table2 b 
 ORDER BY a.datetime DESC;
```

I have fifteen records in table1 a, and two records in table2 b where `b.pid=a.id`.

Only one of those records from table b is being pulled into the result at any given time. Both should be pulled in as bpid, but only the latter of the two makes the trip.

I've also tried using `CASE` (tried `CASE` first, actually):

```
 SELECT a.*, (CASE WHEN b.pid=a.id THEN b.id ELSE NULL END) AS bpid 
 FROM table1 a, table2 b 
 ORDER BY a.datetime DESC;
```

What am I missing?

For clarity: I get all 15 records from table1 a in the result, but not both records from table2 b.

Comment: can you show us the data, please? Maybe via a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not joining the tables correctly. As a tip just stop using commas in the FROM clause, this will help make you consider what the joins should be.

```
/* for all records */
SELECT
      a.*
    , b.id AS bpid
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.DATETIME DESC
```

or

```
/* for only matching records */
SELECT
      a.*
    , b.id AS bpid
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.DATETIME DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. Testing. Back in a minute.

Comment: It works. Thanks very much. I've learned something. Much appreciated.